# Is the family of regular languages closed under the operation of set difference?

Tags: regular-language

Prove that the family of regular languages is closed under the operation of set difference.

(I tried coming up with an NFA that will recognize the new language, but I get stuck with defining the transition function.)

Comment: What closure properties of the class of regular languages do you know?

Comment: @bambam Please explain how you attempted to solve the problem? This will prevent people from downvoting your post.

Comment: @Arbuja I tried coming up with an NFA that will recognize the new language, but I get stuck with defining the transition function.

Comment: @bambam Be sure to include this in your original post. More people will try and answer your question.

Comment: @PhoemueX union, concatenation and Kleene star

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From set theory we get
$$
L_1 \setminus L_2 = L_1 \cap L_2^c
$$

So you can reduce this problem to closure of regular languages regarding set intersection and set complement.

Regularity of $L_1 \cap L_2$ should follow from product automaton construction from a DFA for $L_1$ and $L_2$ each.

Set complement should follow from taking a DFA for $L_2$ and turning final states into normal states and vice versa.